# Access to Windows event observer with ODBC

Tags: windows, export, odbc

Is there a way to access the Windows Event Observer data from something like an ODBC datasource?

Or a way to export data (lets say that we limit age of data to 1 week or one month) in a structured file format (csv ? xml ?) or similar?

Comment: What is this "Windows Event Observer" you speak of?  Do you mean "Windows Event Viewer?"  And, more to the point, are you asking about accessing the Windows Event Logs from an ODBC connection (or similar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that is a foreign language translation and he is referring to the Windows Event Viewer.  you can accomplish this with powershell and simply export events into another format but you'd have to build something to do this.  In powershell  `Get-EventLog` is probably where you want to start.  Keep in mind that in Windows Server 2008+ there are application logs as well that have a different interface and it requires a WMI query to get info.